# loading an excel workbook in my local system works but same not working in my amazon aws(clound instance))

Tags: python, vba, excel, amazon-web-services

I am trying to work on manipulating excel sheets in python with openpyxl module

I am trying to load excel work book in my local system

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import openpyxl
>>> 
>>> wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('GCD_FINAL_OUTPUT.xlsx')
>>> 
>>>
```

Which is working fine

But i tried the same in amazon aws(cloud instance) machine

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import openpyxl
>>> wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('GCD_FINAL_OUTPUT.xlsx')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 201, in load_workbook
    apply_stylesheet(archive, wb) # bind styles to workbook
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/styles/stylesheet.py", line 164, in apply_stylesheet
    stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/styles/stylesheet.py", line 99, in from_tree
    return  super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/serialisable.py", line 89, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/styles/stylesheet.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.named_styles =  self._merge_named_styles()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/styles/stylesheet.py", line 110, in _merge_named_styles
    xf = self.cellStyleXfs[style.xfId]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/styles/cell_style.py", line 182, in __getitem__
    return self.xf[idx]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Which is throwing some random error

how could i fix and make it working??

Comment: What is the version of `openpyxl` on both machines? `pip freeze | grep openpyxl`

Answer (score 0):

The module versions from my local and cloud differs.

By install correct module it works fine